# How to address readers/viewers in an article or video?

Tags: pronouns

How should one address readers or viewers in a published work?

For example, it is common in English language articles and videos these days to end by asking the viewer to share their opinion in a reply or comment.

Ex. "What do you think - do you agree?"  "Does this ever happened to you, and if so, how do you handle it?" "Tell us your pick for the next Batman villain" etc...

These all have a real emphasis on the "you" part though, and the concept of "you" is something I'm struggling to deal with in Japanese.  I've been told to avoid pronouns like あなた, but in a situation where you're speaking or writing to an unknown number of anonymous someones across a divide of time and space, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 読者のみなさん(or 皆様) for readers, 視聴者のみなさん(or 皆様) for viewers and フォロワーのみなさん(or 皆様) for your followers in your SNS like Twitter.